# Android: How to use more than 1 package in the Facebook app configuration

Tags: android, facebook

Can i have more than 1 package name in the Facebook configuration settings to work with Facebook API in my application.

[image]

I must be able to use the same Facebook app for different Android apps right?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

you only need a key hash. No need to enter package name and class name. For your Facebook Integration.

Comment: first you run your app and then when key hash generates in your logcat then put your hash key here and save.

Comment: Yeah. all that is done and it works fine, But what is the use of giving package name?? because it says **This is a required field for Native Linking**. what does that mean?

Comment: you just click on Native android app not other thing..i recently checked that it does not required the package name...

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to create a new Facebook app for each of your Android apps. Multiple package names would break many features, such as deep linking. I think it's also used for storing Facebook permissions so users can easily revoke an app's permissions.

Answer (score 0):

I think, know it is possible to add more than one package names to the Facebook app.

[image]